# Catched error in findOne() method is not descriptive with SailsJS

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm new to NodeJs and SailsJs
When I make a this query:

```
 try {
    route = await Routes.findOne({profile: profileId, url: url})
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).json(e);
  }
```

And try to catch the error, I get:

```
{cause: {name: "Error"}, isOperational: true}
```

which is not helping.

Is there a way to have a better description of the error when executing ORM operations ?

Comment: I think if you log the error object, you'll get to see more.

Comment: with console.log(e) ?

Comment: Yes. Try it and post the result back.

Answer (score 0):

Log a message or some data at the "debug" log level using Sails' built-in 
    logger.

```
 sails.log(...)
```

more details about sails logger can be found [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/application/sails-log).